# redirect specific ip addresses when visiting a page

Tags: php

Can anyone help me with this code?, i'm trying to redirect specific ip addresses (exists in ips.txt) when visiting a page.

the code:

```
<?php
ob_start(); //first line

// get the visitor ip.
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))   //check ip from share internet
    {
      $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']."\r\n";
    }
elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))   //to check if ip is pass from proxy
    {
      $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']."\r\n";
    }
else
    {
      $ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."\r\n";
    }


// check if the visitor ip exists in the txt file
$s = file_get_contents('ips.txt');
$pos = strpbrk($ipaddress, $s);

if ($pos === false) {
    // If it doesn't exist, record the IP in the txt file and then switch to an external page
    $ips = fopen("ips.txt", "a");
    fwrite($ips, $ipaddress . "\n");
    header("Location: https://google.com/");
} else {
    // If it exists, do nothing or switch to an external page
    header("Location: https://example.com"); 
}
?>
```

Comment: You are missing `;` at the end of your fwrite call.

Comment: i dont think you realise that IP!=user

Comment: I fixed this, but the problem still exists. The php code redirects to example.com in both cases (there is an IP address in the txt file or none)

Comment: @smith I know that the ipaddress is constantly changing.

Comment: That can be very slow on a big file. If I were you I'd store the ips in database.

Answer (score 0):

```
$s = file_get_contents("ips.txt");
if(strpos($ipaddress, $s) !== false){
// IP exists
}
```